# Search strings that contain a string in an array in java

Tags: java, android, algorithm, search, data-structures

Consider an array of strings below:
`String[] items = new String[] {"Dani","Liam", "Noah" , "Elijah" , "Emma", "Ava Olivia"};`
I want to search inside this array. As an example i want to find all items that start with *D* or have a single *D* inside it.
When i search ***E*** , the result must be `{"Elijah","Emma"}` and When i search ***Em*** , the *Elijah* will remove and result must be `{"Emma"}`.
When i search for ***Olivia*** the result must be `{"Ava Olivia"}`.
I've tried to split array with *SPACE* and save all words in 2D array, Then i could check first letter of each. There is some bugs in my way.
Thanks for all suggestions.

***PS***  : Note that i'm developing an android application that needs this feature.

Comment: Can you show us some attempts?

Comment: Please add your code and everything you found out during debugging it.

Comment: Please give us the entire filtering logic you want.  I see multiple rules above.

Answer (score 5):

One approach uses a stream with filtering logic:

```
String[] items = new String[] {"Dani","Liam", "Noah" , "Elijah" , "Emma", "Ava Olivia"};
List<String> matches = Arrays.stream(items)
                             .filter(i -> i.startsWith("Em"))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You may apply any filtering logic you want in the call to `filter(...)`.

Comment: Won't work for `Olivia`, shouldn't it be `contains` instead of `startsWith`?

Comment: But this won't cover the case "Olivia" that must return "Ava Olivia"

Comment: @BothOfYou The OP appears (at least to me) to give multiple filtering logic.  I'm not sure there is one single answer for this.

Comment: Yes, could be interpreted that way... Someone who reads the comments may make his own conclusions then.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Useful , but i should add more filters to find Olivia

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution for your program.

This technique can also check for the instances of the searching String in the middle of the name also.

```
String[] names={"Dani","Liam", "Noah", "Elijah", "Emma", "Ava Olivia"};// The names to be search in

Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
String search=in.next();//The word input for filtering the names

ArrayList<String> filered=new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    if(names[i].contains(search))
        filtered.add(names[i]);
}

System.out.println(filtered);
```

**This code will check not only if the name starts with the searching word but also if the name contains the word in the middle of the name also**.

*The filtered names are stored in the ArrayList named filtered here. You can do any other things whatever you wish with the filtered words stored inside the ArrayList*

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Object[] searchItem(String[] items, String searchStr) {
  ArrayList<String> searchedItem = new ArrayList<>();
  for(String string: items) {
    if (string.toLowerCase().contains(searchStr.toLowerCase())) {
        searchedItem.add(string);
    }
  } 
  
  return searchedItem.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that uses the stream API as one of the other answers does, but uses `contains` instead of `startsWith` in order to find `"Ava Olivia"` when the search term is `"Olivia"`:

```
public static List<String> findIn(String filterBy, String[] searchIn) {
    return Arrays.stream(searchIn)
                 .filter(item -> item.contains(filterBy))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can use it this way in a `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] items = new String[] {"Dani","Liam", "Noah" , "Elijah" , "Emma", "Ava Olivia"};
    
    System.out.println(String.join(", ", findIn("Olivia", items)));
}
```

The output of this example is

```
Ava Olivia
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all cases:

```
String[] items = new String[] {"Dani","Liam", "Noah" , "Elijah" , "Emma", "Ava Olivia"};
String searchterm = "Olivia"; 
List<String> matches = Arrays.stream(items)
        .filter(i -> {
            boolean match = false;
            for(String token: i.split("\\s+")){
                if (token.startsWith(searchterm)) {
                    match = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return match;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Simplified (all streams) version:

```
String[] items = new String[] {"Dani","Liam", "Noah" , "Elijah" , "Emma", "Ava Olivia"};
String searchterm = "Olivia";
List<String> matches = Arrays.stream(items)
        .filter(i -> Arrays.stream(i.split("\\s+")).anyMatch(token -> token.startsWith(searchterm)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```